# Activate Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am having troubles trying to activate monotouch 5.1.1

I have purchased the licence however I can't seem to get the activate window to appear.

I have searched in the developer folder and also the library folder for anything that looks like Licence or activate but I cant see anything.

I can't deploy to iphone due to it not be activated.

Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you downloaded and installed the **full** version of MonoTouch. The **evaluation** version is incomplete (e.g. it lack the native compilers) and will not ask (or allow) you to activate your license.

You can get the **full** version from the [customer self-service](http://activation.monotouch.net/) by using your activation code.

Comment: Hi poupou, I did give that a try but I get an error Installation cannot proceed without completing activation. ERR17

Comment: Please contact support@xamarin.com for further assistance

Comment: Thanks I have just emailed them now.

Answer (score 1):

Install Mono and MonoDevelop prior to installing MonoTouch. I had the same error and after installing above mentioned packages activation worked fine. See MonoTouch installation instructions for links to mono and monodevelop: http://ios.xamarin.com/documentation/installation 
cheers,
--henon